# Difference of 01 value on total sum

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a small problem to get the correct total of invoice.

I have on sql table

```
unit_price decimal(25,2)
vat varchar(55)
total_novat decimal(25,2)
total_vat decimal(25,2)
grand_total decimal(25,2)
```

the php script to get the values is:

```
$discount = 2
$total_novat += qty * unit_price / discount
$total_vat = qty * vat / 100
$grand_total = total_novat + total_vat
```

Good, now if i make this simple script the result on values is:

```
unit_price: 1 * 241.14 / 2 = 120.57
total_novat: 120.57 * 24 / 100 = 28.94
grand_total: 120.57 + 28.94 = 149.51
```

the problem is that when i put this code in php the result is 149.50 not 149.51

Any help is appreciated.

full script to perform the calculation:

```
<?php
$inv_total_no_tax = 0;

                for($i=1; $i<=TOTAL_ROWS; $i++){
                    if( $this->input->post($quantity.$i) && $this->input->post($product.$i) && $this->input->post($unit_price.$i) && $this->input->post($discount.$i) ) {

                        $tax_id = $this->input->post($tax_rate.$i);
                        $tax_details = $this->sales_model->getTaxRateByID($tax_id);
                        $taxRate = $tax_details->rate;
                        $taxType = $tax_details->type;  
                        $tax_rate_id[] = $tax_id;               

                        $inv_quantity[] = $this->input->post($quantity.$i);
                        $inv_product_code[] = $this->input->post($product.$i);
                        $inv_unit_price[] = $this->input->post($unit_price.$i) / $this->input->post($discount.$i);
                        $inv_unit_discount[] = $this->input->post($discount.$i);
                        $inv_gross_total[] = (($this->input->post($quantity.$i)) * ($this->input->post($unit_price.$i)) / ($this->input->post($discount.$i)));

                        if($taxType = 1) {
                        $val_tax[] = (($this->input->post($quantity.$i)) * ($this->input->post($unit_price.$i)) / ($this->input->post($discount.$i)) * $taxRate / 100);
                        } else {
                        $val_tax[] = $taxRate;
                        }

                        if($taxType = 1) { $tax[] = $taxRate."%"; } else { $tax[] = $taxRate;  }

                        $inv_total_no_tax += (($this->input->post($quantity.$i)) * ($this->input->post($unit_price.$i)) / ($this->input->post($discount.$i)));

                    }
                }

                 $total_tax = array_sum($val_tax);
                 $total = $inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax;
```

Round option in php script i changed the decimal mysql to varchar.

```
if i use $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 2); the result is: 149.5
if i use $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 3); the result is: 149.501
```

Solution:

Before introduce it to mysql i have applied this string.

```
number_format($value, 2, null, '');
```

Comment: Because you're working with floating point numbers. Google for "floating point error" to see a lot of topics on that.

Comment: How are you handling rounding numbers? `total_noval = 28.9368`

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or
Why don’t my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: the rounding numbers is saved automatic by decimal(25,2) on sql table.

Comment: In that case, what you are getting is truncation, not the arithmetic rounding you are expecting. Round your final result before saving it.

Comment: It seams you dont use sprintf('%.2f', round(grand_total + 100) / 100) to get to digets after point. It seams you only usw sprintf('%.2f', grand_total). A simple convert to 2 digets dont round.

Comment: @datasage: how would he get a truncation if `120.57 * 24 / 100 = 28.94` - is a properly *rounded* result

Comment: Are your values _really_ possibly 25 significant figures in length?  It seems like a waste to use columns that big.  Each of those fields uses 23 bytes.

Comment: @zerkms the php code is not doing that, the value being inserted into the database is `149.5068` Mysql will truncate the remaining digits.

Comment: @datasage: "the php code is not doing that" --- this is what I see in the question. And it *is* rounding. I don't see how it's possible to get rounding in one place, and truncation in another.

Comment: P.S. my calculation was wrong and I was too late to correct it, each DECIMAL(25,2) field uses 12 bytes.

Comment: $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 4); the result is 149.5010 wich is really strange...

Comment: (1 * 241.14 / 2) + (1 * 241.14 / 2) * 24 / 100 = 149.5068 so why are you complaining?

Comment: if i use $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 2); the result is: 149.5
if i use $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 3); the result is: 149.501

Comment: the big problem is that the price without vat and with discount is: 120.57 + vat 28.94 = 149.50 and if you take the calculator and sum 120.57 + 28.94 the result is 149.51

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with an assumption you made in your example calculation

```
unit_price: 1 * 241.14 / 2 = 120.57
total_novat: 120.57 * 24 / 100 = 28.94
grand_total: 120.57 + 28.94 = 149.51
```

If that is treated without rounding it will look like this (this is what is happening in your php code):

```
unit_price: 1 * 241.14 / 2 = 120.57
total_novat: 120.57 * 24 / 100 = 28.9368
grand_total: 120.57 + 28.9368 = 149.5068
```

If you insert this value `149.5068` into mysql it will be stored as `149.50` (mysql will truncate, not round, the additional digits if stored in a decimal column). Instead you need to round your final calculation so that the final value is `149.51`

Comment: exactly, i fixed the issue with number_format($value, 2, null, ''); before introduce it in to mysql table. Thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

instead of decimal(25,2) try decimal(25,3) and then round your number after doing all of the calculations. This will make your decimals more accurate. It's usually best to store as accurate of a number as possible, then format it after all calculations are done.

Comment: if i change the decimal to 3 in db will show me everywhere the 3 decimal result, even if is 0 at final, and i need 2 decimal. the result is correct, only the sum is incorrect. because  120.57 + 28.94 = 149.50 and i cannot understand why.

Comment: @Dario: how **exactly** are you performing the calculations? Give the full script that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes, thats why I said to round it after your final calculations. So, before display the number, just do number_format($grand_total, 2);

Comment: i have updated the question with the full script performing the calculation steps.

Comment: @Piontek Media: don't you confuse `number_format` with `round`?

Comment: @Dario: provide a **php** script that we could use to run - so we could just **copy paste** and nothing more to see the issue.

Comment: @zerkms the php is based on codeigniter and to post the full script i need to attach the entire controller with model and view.

Comment: @zerkms - I just assumed that he wanted it formatted in dollars since there isn't enough info. Number format will give you the thousand seperators, round() will not give thousand seperators but gives you more options ie round half up, round half down, etc. Not quite sure which one he needs.

Comment: all numbers are rounded to 2 decimals in database, and on post is getting the price from products, applying the discount getting the vat on  a separate column and getting the total sum at final. but the total sum is getting incorrect with 1 decimal.

Comment: Yes...that's why I suggested to store them as 3 decimals so you have more accurate numbers for calculations, and then round them after all calculations are done.

Comment: @Dario: we cannot run your script to see your issue - there are too much dependencies for it.

Comment: $total = round($inv_total_no_tax + $total_tax, 4); the result is 149.5010 wich is really strange...